# Order properties of R

Tags: analysis

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ be such that

1. $a,b \in S \Rightarrow ab, a+b \in S$
2. for all $x \in R$, exactly one of the following holds

$x \in S$ or $x=0$ or $-x \in S$

Show that $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x > 0\}$.

I'm not sure I understand the question.

If $x>0$, then obviously, $x\in S$.

Why does include $S$ only includes elements $x$ such that $x>0$?

I mean, I know this is the trichotomy property. But right now, we define an $S$ which can most probably be to any real numbers, not just $\mathbb{P}$ like in the order properties of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $-x$ doesn't mean it is negative always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we **prove** that if $x\gt0$ then $x\in S$. I suppose you already know that every positive number has a positive square root. Let $y$ be the positive square root of $x$, so $y^2=x$ and $y\gt0$. Either $y\in S$ or $y=0$ or $-y\in S$. Since $y\not=0$, either $y\in S$ or $-y\in S$. If $y\in S$ then $x=yy\in S$; if $-y\in S$ then $x=(-y)(-y)\in S$. Either way, $x\in S$.

We have shown that $S$ contains all the positive numbers; we have to show that $S$ does not contain any negative numbers or $0$.

If $x=0$ then, since **only** one of the statements "$x\in S,x=0,-x\in S$ holds, and since the middle one holds, neither of the others can hold; in particular $x\in S$ is false, i.e., $x\not\in S$. Thus $0\not\in S$.

Finally suppose $x\lt0$; we have to show that $x\not\in S$. Again, only one of the three statements holds. Since $-x\gt0$, we know that $-x\in S$; hence $x\not\in S$.

Answer (score 1):

Once you say "If $x \gt 0$, then obviously, $x \in S$" you can use 2. to see that $-x \not \in S$.   You are being asked to justify the "obviously".  This is defining the positive numbers.  $S$ is a set, it doesn't map anything.  Probably you are going to show that $S$ exists within $\Bbb R$.  From this exercise, it could be that there is no $S \in \Bbb R$ that satisfies both of these-in the complex numbers it fails.

Comment: So, @bof's answer above uses the existence of square roots in $\mathbb{R}$, but doesn't use the fact that $S$ is closed under addition. You mentioned that the conditions on $S$ given in the statement of the problem _define_ the positive numbers. Do you mean _define_ in the sense of first-order logic? The reason I ask is that completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ is a second-order property, and the only way I know to show existence of square roots is via completeness, which I think would make it a second-order property as well. The question is: does there exist a "first-order proof" of this problem?

Comment: @J.Loreaux:  I think this would come before square roots, so we can't use them.  You can also do it in $\Bbb Q$ without completeness.  As I said, this looks like the definition of the positive numbers, so I don't know what definition of greater than is being used.  I would think you want to prove that such an $S$ exists.  Then you call it the positive numbers and define $x \gt y$ if $y+s=x$ for some $s \in S$

Comment: That's what I figured. Thus far I've been able to show that every positive rational lies in $S$. I would then like to make the jump to algebraic numbers, but afterwards I would still be stuck on the transcendental case. If you have an idea of the proof could you update your answer to include this? I would be rather interested. Or at least provide a sketch in the comments.